# Delphi - Write string to Reg_Binary registry key

Tags: delphi, registry

I need to convert a string to write it into a registry.reg_binary key.

I have the basic code for writing into the key as follows:

```
try
   rootkey := HKEY_CURRENT_USER;
   if OpenKey(Key, False) then
   begin
      reg.WriteBinaryData('SomeKey', SomeValue, Length(SomeVale));
      CloseKey;
   end;
finally
   reg.Free;
end;
```

In the above, **SomeValue** needs to be the hex value of a TEdit text field;

My current tack is convert the TEdit.text using IntToHex on the Ord value of each character.  This gives me a string that looks like what I want to write...

At this point I'm stumped...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Granted this assumes that your string only contains ansi data,
but if your trying to write a string to a registry value as a binary value then the following changes to your logic would work:

```
var
  EdStr : AnsiString;
:
  EdStr := AnsiString(Edit1.Text); // de-unicode
  reg.WriteBinaryData('SomeKey', EdStr[1], Length(EdStr));
```

Comment: Thanks for that - I still need to pad the string out with #00 to get the format the receiving application requires, but this is bang on!

Answer (score 6):

If you want to write a string, then you should call [`WriteString`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Registry.TRegistry.WriteString).

```
reg.WriteString('SomeKey', SomeValue);
```

If you have an integer, then call [`WriteInteger`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Registry.TRegistry.WriteInteger).

```
IntValue := StrToInt(SomeValue);
reg.WriteInteger('SomeKey', IntValue);
```

If you have true binary data, then it shouldn't matter what it looks like — hexadecimal or whatever. Call [`WriteBinaryData`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Registry.TRegistry.WriteBinaryData) and be done with it. The actual appearance of the data is immaterial because you don't have to read it in that format. You'll read it later with [`ReadBinaryData`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Registry.TRegistry.ReadBinaryData) and it will fill your buffer with the bytes in whatever format they had when you wrote them.

```
IntValue := StrToInt(SomeValue);
reg.WriteBinaryValue('SomeKey', IntValue, SizeOf(IntValue));
```

That will write all four bytes of your integer into the registry as a binary value.

When the Windows Registry Editor displays the key's value to you, it will probably display each byte in hexadecimal, but that's just a *display format*. It doesn't mean you have to format your data like that before you add it to the registry.

Comment: Unfortunately not the case.  Changing my code to use WriteString changes the key in the registry to a REG_SZ key, which the receiving application cannot write.  

RegEdit displays the REG_SZ key as plain text not the hex value seen when looking at the detail entered by the other program.

StrToInt on a true text value blows up of course